# To provide the key insight of this method

Tags: prepositions, possessives, redundancy

Is the following sentence grammatical?

> To provide the key insight of this method, we make use of an example
>   to illustrate it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the noun *[insight](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/insight)* in this context better go with preposition *into*. So, *insight into (something)*.

> To provide insight *into* this method, we use an example to illustrate it.

Note: I avoided the superfluous words.

Comment: +1 Even better: An example provides insight into this method. As Browning said, "Less is more."